# Why doesn't Evaluate appear to work in this RegionPlot example with MatchQ?

Tags: evaluation

I am trying to plot the region over which a function of two (real) parameters `a` and `b` is real-valued, using `RegionPlot` and `MatchQ`. In general this will be a complicated function with real and complex parts, but to illustrate the query I will use a simple function, `a^2 + b^2`:

```
RegionPlot[MatchQ[(a^2 + b^2), _Real],{a,-2,2},{b,-2,2}]
```

As expected, `RegionPlot` colors the whole region. This is because `RegionPlot` presumably evaluates its predicate - here `MatchQ` - on the a,b mesh before plotting, so that the expression `a^2+b^2` in `MatchQ` is manifestly real, i.e. the `Head` of the resulting expression is `Real` and `MatchQ` evaluates to `True`. On its own however, with no contextual information on `a` or `b`,

```
MatchQ[(a^2 + b^2), _Real]
```

evaluates to

```
False
```

as expected. Now if I replace `a^2+b^2` with

```
Evaluate[Expand[(a + I b) (a - I b)]]
```

i.e.

```
RegionPlot[MatchQ[Evaluate[Expand[(a + I b) (a - I b)]], _Real],{a,-2,2},{b,-2,2}]
```

`RegionPlot` displays a completely blank region (also the case for `ComplexExpand`). Since `Evaluate` should have presumably overridden the `HoldAll` attribute of `RegionPlot`, I would have expected the expression to evaluate to `Real` and therefore for the `MatchQ` to evaluate to `True`, so why doesn't `RegionPlot` display the region in this case?

Comment: `Evaluate` overrides only `Hold`-attributes of heads immediately enclosing it, but you have another layer here (`MatchQ`). [This discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808) might help.

Comment: thanks for the link: yes, a useful and comprehensive discussion on lexical vs dynamic scoping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, the `Evaluate` is only evaluated immediately if it is top level in the argument, as the following code shows:

```
ClearAll[test];SetAttributes[test,HoldAll];test[x_]:=Hold[x]
test[Evaluate[1+1]]
(*
==> Hold[2]
*)
test[f[Evaluate[1+1]]]
(*
==> Hold[f[Evaluate[1+1]]]
*)
```

Since in your code it is not top level, it is passed on together with the rest of the expression to `RegionPlot`. It is evaluated at a point where the variables already have numerical values. And this gives a *complex* result with imaginary part numerically zero, as the following proves:

```
ClearAll[f];SetAttributes[f,HoldAll];f[x_]:=Block[{a=1.,b=1.},x]
f[Head[Evaluate[(a+I b)(a-I b)]]]
(*
==> Complex
*)
f[(a+I b)(a-I b)]
(*
==> 2.+0. I
*)
```

You can get rid of the numerically zero imaginary part by using `Chop`:

```
RegionPlot[MatchQ[Chop@Evaluate[Expand[(a+I b) (a-I b)]],_Real],{a,-2,2},{b,-2,2}]
```

More generally, to evaluate just part of an expression passed to a function with `HoldAll` attribute, you can use `With`:

```
With[{expr=Expand[(a+I b)(a-I b)]},
     RegionPlot[MatchQ[expr,_Real],{a,-2,2},{b,-2,2}]]
```

Comment: Many thanks: I suspect Chopping will likely be required with the actual function concerned so appreciate the pointer. Useful tip on the evaluation sequence.

Comment: @NCM: Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried to fix your code, but I suppose I would try to plot the region like so

```
RegionPlot[Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)] == 
  Re[Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Or even using `DensityPlot`, which only plots spots where the function is real.

```
DensityPlot[Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: `RegionPlot[Im[Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)]] == 0, ...]` works as well.

Comment: thanks - the function in my example wasn't so important really and in practice will be much more complicated anyway; I wanted to understand the evaluation mechanism which (I think) I now do.