# Plotting function with unique symbols

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot a function which involves multiple symbols created using `Unique`. Consider the following simple example.

```
X = {Unique["x"]}
Plot[Evaluate[2 X[[1]]], {Evaluate[X[[1]]], 0, 1}]
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error *Plot::write: "Tag Evaluate in Evaluate[X[[1]]] is Protected."*.

Is there a way to plot using "dynamic" variables?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(7756)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121), [(20718)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20718/121), [(46751)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46751/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It seems to me the underlying problem is that `Evaluate` should be placed outside the list, `Evaluate@{X[[1]], 0, 1}`.  This is the issue in many posts, such as [(5235)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5235) and [(47907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47907), and is also explained in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35359).  I couldn't find one in which the issue was specifically using `Evaluate` in the second argument to `Plot`.  It's usually the first argument.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, those are good, perhaps better, originals.  And I found another related question and added it to my comment above.  This question seems headed toward closure as "in the documentation" at this point; hopefully the links are useful to Markus and others.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a relatively recent version of *Mathematica*, you don't need to use `Evaluate`.

```
X = {Unique["x"]};
With[{x = X[[1]]}, Plot[Legended[2 x, x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Using `X={Unique["x"]};Plot[Legended[2 X[[1]], X[[1]]], {X[[1]], 0, 1}]` does not work. I need something that works for symbol lists.

Comment: @MarkusMüller  Please edit your question to state clearly what you do need.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I fixed it. Basically, I am wondering how to plot a function which depends on "dynamic" variables created using `Unique`.

Comment: `With` solves the problem. Thanks.